# how to configure pylint for E0611: No name 'xxxx' in module 'xxx' (no-name-in-module)?

Tags: python, pytest, pylint

```
├── src
├──── events
├────── foo_bar
├──────── pop_bou
├────────── app.py

def handler() -> Optional[dict]:
    return None
```

**and my pytest file is:**

```
def test_foo():

    from events.foo_bar.pop_bou.app import handler
    ...
```

When I run pylint, I have this error:

```
E0611: No name 'foo_bar' in module 'events' (no-name-in-module)
```

Comment: If it works and imports ok, disabling the warning is reasonable here.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in each source directory? Where is the test directory for pytest in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update your `src` directory structure as follows:

```
src
└── events
    └── foo_bar
        └── pop_bou
            ├── __init__.py
            └── app.py
```

and make sure to add an empty `__init__.py` file in the pop_bou directory to make it a python package.
NExt you can configure `Pylint` by adding a `.pylintrc` file in the root of your project or specifying the configuration options in your `pylintrc` section of your `pyproject.toml` file.

```
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("src")'
```